# How to turn off 'protected-mode' in Redis?

Tags: redis, redis-sentinel

I'd like to disable `protected-mode` on my production Redis. Regarding to the following error I got from my other Redis-Sentinel instance I could disable it live by connecting to Redis from the master machine it runs on.

> DENIED Redis is running in protected mode because protected mode is
>   enabled, no  bind address was specified, no authentication password is
>   requested to clients.  In this mode connections are only accepted from
>   the loopback interface. If you  want to connect from external
>   computers to Redis you may adopt one of the  following solutions:
>
> 1) Just disable protected mode sending the command 'CONFIG SET
>   protected-mode no' from the loopback interface by connecting to
>   Redis from the same host the server is running, however MAKE SURE
>   Redis is not publicly accessible from internet if you do so. Use
>   CONFIG REWRITE to make this change permanent.
>
> 2) Alternatively you can just disable the protected mode by editing
>   the Redis configuration file, and setting the protected mode
>   option to 'no', and then restarting the server.
>
> 3) If you started the server manually just for testing, restart it
>   with the '--protected-mode no' option.
>
> 4) Setup a bind address or an authentication password.
>
> NOTE: You only need to do one of the above things in order for 
>   the server to start accepting connections from the outside.

But as I connect and try to disable it I get the Error `(error) ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: protected-mode`.

There's no auth configured or anything else - all security is managed by firewall rules. The `redis.conf` is almost default.

#### Demo

```
root@svim-redis03 /etc/redis # redis-cli

127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG GET protected*
(empty list or set)
127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG GET bind*
1) "bind"
2) "127.0.0.1"
127.0.0.1:6379> CONFIG SET protected-mode no
(error) ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: protected-mode
127.0.0.1:6379> exit

root@svim-redis03 /etc/redis # redis-server --version
Redis server v=3.2.9 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-4.0.3 bits=64 build=86450d2ba8219c1e
```

Is there anything I need to check or change before? I couldn't find any hint in the [documentation](https://redis.io/topics/security) or in [GitHub issues](https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20protected-mode%20).

#### Update 01

It's not even possible to change the bind-address or any other config parameter. Do I need to enable config changes first?

```
127.0.0.1:6379> config set bind "127.0.0.1 11.12.13.14"
(error) ERR Unsupported CONFIG parameter: bind
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out that the current server running isn't the same version as the binary I've installed.

## How to reproduce this?

Simply connect via `redis-cli` to your redis instance and type `INFO server` which returns a bunch of informations.

```
127.0.0.1:6379> INFO server
# Server
redis_version:3.0.7
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:869e89100d5ea8c2
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 4.2.0-35-generic x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.8.4
process_id:26720
run_id:6645270dd2ac6a7f96caa054f9dbba9e66566755
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:10971777
uptime_in_days:126
hz:10
lru_clock:6676576
config_file:/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

As you can see this redis-instance runs almost 127 days and uses `redis_version:3.0.7`.

## How to fix this?

Restart your server and be sure that you realy restarted it! For example with most Linux distros you can do so by hitting the following commands.

```
root@svim-redis03 ~ # service redis-server stop
Stopping redis-server: redis-server.
```

Check if it's really offline by trying to connect with `redis-cli`. If you still can connect the instance is still running. Check this by searching for active redis processes.

```
root@svim-redis03 ~ # ps -efl |grep redis
1 S redis    12418     1  0  80   0 - 10673 ep_pol  2016 ?        05:33:17 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6381
1 S redis    12442     1  0  80   0 - 11697 ep_pol  2016 ?        05:33:46 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6382
1 S redis    12453     1  0  80   0 - 10673 ep_pol  2016 ?        05:40:17 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6383
4 S root     16570 16386  0  80   0 -  2489 wait_w 10:42 pts/7    00:00:00 tail -f /var/log/redis/redis-server-6379.log
0 S root     17064 12637  0  80   0 -  3617 pipe_w 10:47 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto redis
1 S redis    26720     1  0  80   0 - 453041 ep_pol Mar07 ?       08:37:01 /usr/bin/redis-server 127.0.0.1:6379
```

As you can see there's still the instance (process id: 26720) running. Quit it with the following command.

```
kill 26720
```

After you've killed the process check again with `ps -efl |grep redis` if the instance is really down.

Finally start it again with

```
root@svim-redis03 ~ # service redis-server start
Starting redis-server: redis-server.
```

Now check if the instance is running with the correct version.

```
root@svim-redis03 ~ # redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> INFO server
# Server
redis_version:3.2.9
redis_git_sha1:00000000
redis_git_dirty:0
redis_build_id:86450d2ba8219c1e
redis_mode:standalone
os:Linux 4.2.0-35-generic x86_64
arch_bits:64
multiplexing_api:epoll
gcc_version:4.8.4
process_id:17135
run_id:40d6fa2e2b25e8f5b97a3c97ec1bddb8edda0014
tcp_port:6379
uptime_in_seconds:11
uptime_in_days:0
hz:10
lru_clock:6677102
executable:/usr/bin/redis-server
config_file:/etc/redis/redis.conf
```

Comment: I can't believe it, but I had exactly the same issue: 2 different servers were running on the box. Mind blowing! Thank you for an answer... but why...why?! 